# Loop tables in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, for-loop, dynamic-sql

I need to create a Materialized view to loop all worklist tables from `pg_tables`.

First I create a query and after tried to create a for loop.

This my first code **without the for loop.**

```
SELECT 
count(visit_num) AS total_claim_count,
count(user_id) as assigned_count,
(count(visit_num)-count(user_id)) AS not_assigned_count,
count(case when doe <= (SELECT doe - INTERVAL '30 days') and user_id is not null then 1 end ) AS Assigned_Last_30_Days,
(count(user_id)-count(case when doe <= (SELECT doe - INTERVAL '30 days') and user_id is not null then 1 end )) AS not_Assigned_last_30_days,
count(case when doe >= (SELECT doe - INTERVAL '30 days') and user_id is not null then 1 end ) AS Assigned_before_30_Days,
count(case when doe > (SELECT doe - INTERVAL '30 days') and user_id is null then 1 end ) AS not_Assigned_before_30_days,
count(CASE WHEN date_worked is not null then 1 end) followed_up,
count(CASE WHEN last_denied_date is not null then 1 end) denials,
count(case when status_and_action_code='No Status - Need to follow-up' then 1 end) AS no_status
FROM Worklist_123456
```

This is code **with for loop** i tried.but it is not working.

```
DO $$

DECLARE
    pg_tables varchar(1000000);
    tbl_name record;
    tablename varchar(1000000);
    
begin
For tbl_name IN SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tablename LIKE 'worklist¥_%' ESCAPE '¥'

loop

    tablename := tbl_name.tablename;

    SELECT 
    count(visit_num) AS total_claim_count,
    count(user_id) as assigned_count,
    (count(visit_num)-count(user_id)) AS not_assigned_count,
    count(case when doe <= (SELECT doe - INTERVAL '30 days') and user_id is not null then 1 end ) AS Assigned_Last_30_Days,
    (count(user_id)-count(case when doe <= (SELECT doe - INTERVAL '30 days') and user_id is not null then 1 end )) AS not_Assigned_last_30_days,
    count(case when doe >= (SELECT doe - INTERVAL '30 days') and user_id is not null then 1 end ) AS Assigned_before_30_Days,
    count(case when doe > (SELECT doe - INTERVAL '30 days') and user_id is null then 1 end ) AS not_Assigned_before_30_days,
    count(CASE WHEN date_worked is not null then 1 end) followed_up,
    count(CASE WHEN last_denied_date is not null then 1 end) denials,
    count(case when status_and_action_code='No Status - Need to follow-up' then 1 end) AS no_status
    FROM tablename;

END LOOP;

END; $$;
```

It giving error like this.

```
ERROR:  column reference "tablename" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public' ...
               ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
QUERY:  SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tablename LIKE 'worklist¥_%' ESCAPE '¥'
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 9 at FOR over SELECT rows
SQL state: 42702
```

Anyone can help me to fix this issue.Thank you.

Comment: You are missing semicolon after `FROM tablename`; Can you add it and let me know, if you still face issues ?

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for this, using execute. A different datamodel might be a better/ easier solution, something like table inheritance or partitioning

Comment: @FrankHeikens can you guide me to archive this? without loop, it is working properly and generated my expected output for one table.

Comment: @Tushar I fixed that error and again give error after this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75763956/loop-tables-in-postgresql#comment133651199_75763956) by [@Frank Heikens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271959/frank-heikens), you're thinking in [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) terms:
[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Hds6BZYo)

```sql
DO $proc$
DECLARE tbl_name record;
BEGIN
FOR tbl_name IN SELECT tablename 
                FROM  pg_tables 
                WHERE schemaname = 'public' 
                AND   tablename LIKE 'worklist¥_%' ESCAPE '¥'
LOOP execute format($dynamic_sql_query$
        INSERT INTO anon_proc_output
        SELECT 
            %1$L             AS source_table --first argument (1$), as a string Literal (L)
          , count(visit_num) AS total_claim_count
          , count(user_id)   AS assigned_count
          ,(count(visit_num) 
           -count(user_id) ) AS not_assigned_count
          , count(user_id)filter(where doe <= (SELECT doe - INTERVAL '30 days') )   AS Assigned_Last_30_Days
          ,(count(user_id) 
           -count(user_id)filter(where doe <= (SELECT doe - INTERVAL '30 days') ) ) AS not_Assigned_last_30_days
          , count(user_id)filter(where doe >= (SELECT doe - INTERVAL '30 days') )   AS Assigned_before_30_Days
          , count(*)filter(where doe > (SELECT doe - INTERVAL '30 days') 
                           and user_id is null)                                     AS not_Assigned_before_30_days
          , count(date_worked)      AS followed_up
          , count(last_denied_date) AS denials
          , count(*)filter(where status_and_action_code='No Status - Need to follow-up') AS no_status
        FROM %1$s; --still the same first argument, hence the 1$, but this time as-is, hence the s
        $dynamic_sql_query$
      , tbl_name.tablename);--this is used to replace %1$L %1$s
END LOOP;
END $proc$;
```

1. `count(case...)` is emulating aggregate [`FILTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) clause.
2. `doe>=(SELECT doe-INTERVAL '30 days')` makes little sense. You're checking if the value is larger than itself, decreased. That's effectively `some_number>=(some_number-1)`.
3. [`count(arg)` doesn't count rows where `arg` is null](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE):

> `count ( "any" ) → bigint`
> Computes the number of input rows in which the input value **is not null**.

- so `count(case when arg is not null then 1 end)` is the same as `count(arg)`,
- `count(case when (condition) and arg is not null then 1 end)` is the same as `count(arg)filter(where (condition))`.

  You might need to re-think where and why you use `count(arg)` as opposed to `count(*)` and `count(case when arg is not null then 1 end)`.

Answer (score 1):

### [Partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html)

Posting the [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75765608/5298879) solution [separately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25209), to demonstrate [the other suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75763956/loop-tables-in-postgresql/75765608#comment133651199_75763956) from [@Frank Heikens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271959/frank-heikens).

You'd normally select a pre-existing feature that differentiates the partitions, like the range of dates a given one is supposed to hold, data source location identifier, a group of users. I'm adding a dummy column as the key just to show the idea: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/xL8G-Y99)

```sql
create table worklists (like worklist_123457 including all, worklist_name text)
    partition by list(worklist_name);

alter table worklist_123456 add column worklist_name text default 'worklist_123456';
alter table worklist_123457 add column worklist_name text default 'worklist_123457';

alter table worklists attach partition worklist_123456 for values in ('worklist_123456');
alter table worklists attach partition worklist_123457 for values in ('worklist_123457');
```

And then your loop becomes a simple `group by` on the main, collective, aggregating table instead:

```sql
SELECT 
    worklist_name    AS source_table
  , count(visit_num) AS total_claim_count
  , count(user_id)   AS assigned_count
  ,(count(visit_num) 
   -count(user_id) ) AS not_assigned_count
  , count(user_id)filter(where doe <= (SELECT doe - INTERVAL '30 days') )   AS Assigned_Last_30_Days
  ,(count(user_id) 
   -count(user_id)filter(where doe <= (SELECT doe - INTERVAL '30 days') ) ) AS not_Assigned_last_30_days
  , count(user_id)filter(where doe >= (SELECT doe - INTERVAL '30 days') )   AS Assigned_before_30_Days
  , count(*)filter(where doe > (SELECT doe - INTERVAL '30 days') 
                   and user_id is null)                                     AS not_Assigned_before_30_days
  , count(date_worked)      AS followed_up
  , count(last_denied_date) AS denials
  , count(*)filter(where status_and_action_code='No Status - Need to follow-up') AS no_status
FROM worklists
group by worklist_name;
```